# Connect to Jenkins server via SSH

Tags: bash, jenkins, ssh

I was wondering if I can ssh a local instance of Jenkins. When I go to Jenkins CLI menu in the UI, there's a comment saying the below:

> You can access various features in Jenkins through a command-line
> tool. See the documentation for more details of this feature. To get
> started, download jenkins-cli.jar, and run it as follows:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -webSocket help
```

So I tried it and it worked but it only gave a list of limited commands which I can execute. So I searched more and found I can use `-ssh` instead of `-webSocket` but I get the same result as `-webSocket`.

What I want to do is accessing the Jenkins bash so I can test my build scripts.

I'm trying

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 23 // I set this port in the settings
```

but I keep getting :

> shell request failed on channel 0

is it impossible what I'm trying to do? if not, how can I achieve it?

Comment: `ssh` to localhost is effectively the same as just running `bash -l`

Comment: @jordanm thank you, I didn't know that. but I still haven't find an explanation.